# How to do consecutive subsetting in R and plotting counts at each step?

Tags: r, loops, optimization, nested, subset

I have a data frame of 1401 observations of 16 variables. For each column (except the first one), I have either 1 (if a condition is met) or 0 (if a condition is not met).
I subset my data based on all conditions (all columns) in different order (column 1, then column 2, then column 3 etc or column 3, then column 12, then column 1 for example). To compare the different scenarios, I plot the number of observations after each step of the subsetting.

I wrote my code and it works but it is very messy and long and it would definitely benefit from your suggestions.

```
dput(droplevels(head(data,20)))
structure(list(Substance = structure(c(13L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 1L, 
19L, 16L, 17L, 5L, 2L, 14L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 20L, 18L, 15L, 3L, 11L, 
8L), .Label = c("104653-34-1", "107-02-8", "111-30-8", "12057-74-8", 
"122454-29-9", "14915-37-8", "20859-73-8", "27083-27-8", "28772-56-7", 
"3691-35-8", "55965-84-9", "56073-07-5", "56073-10-0", "5836-29-3", 
"71751-41-2", "74-90-8", "81-81-2", "86347-14-0", "90035-08-8", 
"91465-08-6"), class = "factor"), colA = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
    colB = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), colC = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L), colD = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), colE = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L), colF = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), colG = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), colH = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), colI = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L
    ), colK = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), colJ = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L), colL = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), colM = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), colN = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), colO = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("Substance", 
"Oral", "Dermal", "Inhalation", "SC", "SED", "RS", "SS", "M", 
"C", "R", "STOT.SE", "STOT.RE", "AT", "Eco.Acute", "Eco.Chronic"
), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 28L, 34L), class = "data.frame")
#scenario A
#I count the number of observations for each condition
count_0 <- count(data)
count_1 <- sum(data$colA == 1)
count_2 <- sum(data$colA == 1 & data$colB == 1)
count_3 <- sum(data$colA == 1 & data$colB == 1 & data$colC == 1)
count_4 <- sum(data$colA == 1 & data$colB == 1 & data$colC == 1 & data$colD == 1)
count_5 <- sum(data$colA == 1 & data$colB == 1 & data$colC == 1& data$colD == 1 & data$colE == 1)
count_6 <- sum(data$colA == 1 & data$colB == 1 & data$colC == 1 & data$colD == 1 & data$colE == 1 & data$colF == 1)
count_7 <- sum(data$colA == 1 & data$colB == 1 & data$colC == 1& data$colD == 1 & data$colE == 1 & data$colF == 1 & data$colG == 1)
count_8 <- sum(data$colA == 1 & data$colB == 1 & data$colC == 1 & data$colD == 1 & data$colE == 1 & data$colF == 1 & data$colG == 1 & data$colH == 1)
count_9 <- sum(data$colA == 1 & data$colB == 1 & data$colC == 1 & data$colD == 1 & data$colE == 1 & data$colF == 1 & data$colG == 1& data$colH == 1 &                 data$colI == 1)
count_10 <- sum(data$colA == 1 & data$colB == 1 & data$colC == 1 & data$colD == 1 & data$colE == 1 & data$colF == 1 & data$colG == 1& data$colH == 1 & data$colI == 1 & data$colJ == 1)
count_11 <- sum(data$colA == 1 & data$colB == 1 & data$colC == 1 & data$colD == 1 & data$colE == 1 & data$colF == 1 & data$colG == 1 & data$colH == 1 &                  data$colI == 1 & data$colJ == 1 &  data$colK == 1)
count_12 <- sum(data$colA == 1 & data$colB == 1 & data$colC == 1 & data$colD == 1 & data$colE == 1 & data$colF == 1 & data$colG == 1 & data$colH == 1 &                  data$colI == 1 & data$colJ == 1 &  data$colK == 1& data$colL == 1)
count_13 <- sum(data$colA == 1 & data$colB == 1 &  data$colC == 1 & data$colD == 1 & data$colE == 1 & data$colF == 1 &  data$colG == 1& data$colH == 1 &                  data$colI == 1& data$colJ == 1 & data$colK == 1 & data$colL == 1 & data$colM == 1)
count_14 <- sum(data$colA == 1 & data$colB == 1 & data$colC == 1 & data$colD == 1 & data$colE == 1 & data$colF == 1 & data$colG == 1 & data$colH == 1 & data$colI == 1 & data$colJ == 1 & data$colK == 1 & data$colL == 1 & data$colM == 1 & data$colN == 1)
count_15 <- sum(data$colA == 1 & data$colB == 1 & data$colC == 1& data$colD == 1 & data$colE == 1& data$colF == 1 & data$colG == 1 & data$colH == 1 &               data$colI == 1 & data$colJ == 1 & data$colK == 1 & data$colL == 1 & data$colM == 1 & data$colN == 1 & data$colO == 1)
scenarioA <- rbind(count_0,count_1,count_2,count_3,count_4,count_5,count_6,count_7,count_8,count_9,count_10,count_11,count_12,count_13, count_14,count_15)
#I add a column to the new dataframe "scenarioA" to indicate that the results correspond to scenario A (for later use for ggplot)
scenario <- c("scenarioA","scenarioA","scenarioA","scenarioA","scenarioA","scenarioA","scenarioA","scenarioA","scenarioA",            "scenarioA","scenarioA","scenarioA","scenarioA","scenarioA","scenarioA","scenarioA")
scenarioA <- cbind(rownames(scenarioA),scenarioA, scenario)
rownames(scenarioA) <- NULL
colnames(scenarioA) <- c("endpoint","hits","scenario")
#I repeat the same for scenario B but with different order in the subsetting
count_1 <- sum(data$colM == 1)
count_2 <- sum(data$colM == 1 & data$colC == 1)
count_3 <- sum(data$colM == 1 & data$colC == 1 & data$colE == 1)
count_4 <- sum(data$colM == 1 & data$colC == 1 & data$colE == 1 & data$colH == 1)
count_5 <- sum(data$colM == 1 & data$colC == 1 & data$colE == 1 & data$colH == 1 & data$colF == 1)
count_6 <- sum(data$colM == 1 & data$colC == 1 & data$colE == 1 & data$colH == 1 & data$colF == 1 & data$colA == 1)
count_7 <- sum(data$colM == 1 & data$colC == 1 & data$colE == 1 & data$colH == 1 & data$colF == 1 & data$colA == 1 &  data$colD == 1)
count_8 <- sum(data$colM == 1 & data$colC == 1 & data$colE == 1 & data$colH == 1 & data$colF == 1 & data$colA == 1 & data$colD == 1 & data$colO == 1)
count_9 <- sum(data$colM == 1 & data$colC == 1 & data$colE == 1 & data$colH == 1 & data$colF == 1 & data$colA == 1 & data$colD == 1 & data$colO == 1 & data$colI == 1)
count_10 <- sum(data$colM == 1 & data$colC == 1 & data$colE == 1 & data$colH == 1 & data$colF == 1 & data$colA == 1 & data$colD == 1 & data$colO == 1 & data$colI == 1 & data$colG == 1)
count_11 <- sum(data$colM == 1 & data$colC == 1 & data$colE == 1 & data$colH == 1 & data$colF == 1 & data$colA == 1 & data$colD == 1 & data$colO == 1 & data$colI == 1 & data$colG == 1 & data$colB == 1)
count_12 <- sum(data$colM == 1 & data$colC == 1 & data$colE == 1 & data$colH == 1 & data$colF == 1 & data$colA == 1 & data$colD == 1 & data$colO == 1 & data$colI == 1 & data$colG == 1 & data$colB == 1& data$colJ == 1)
count_13 <- sum(data$colM == 1 & data$colC == 1 & data$colE == 1 & data$colH == 1 & data$colF == 1 & data$colA == 1 & data$colD == 1 & data$colO == 1 & data$colI == 1 & data$colG == 1 & data$colB == 1& data$colJ == 1 & data$colL == 1)
count_14 <- sum(data$colM == 1 & data$colC == 1 & data$colE == 1 & data$colH == 1 & data$colF == 1 & data$colA == 1 & data$colD == 1 & data$colO == 1 & data$colI == 1 & data$colG == 1 & data$colB == 1& data$colJ == 1 & data$colL == 1 & data$colN == 1)
count_15 <- sum(data$colM == 1 & data$colC == 1 & data$colE == 1 & data$colH == 1 & data$colF == 1 & data$colA == 1 & data$colD == 1 & data$colO == 1 & data$colI == 1 & data$colG == 1 & data$colB == 1& data$colJ == 1 & data$colL == 1 & data$colN == 1 & data$colK == 1)
#I create a new data frame with the results from the scenario B
scenarioB <- rbind(count_0, count_1,count_2,count_3,count_4,count_5,count_6,count_7,                                count_8,count_9,count_10,count_11,count_12,count_13, count_14,count_15)
scenario <- c("scenarioB","scenarioB","scenarioB","scenarioB","scenarioB","scenarioB","scenarioB","scenarioB","scenarioB",       "scenarioB","scenarioB","scenarioB","scenarioB","scenarioB","scenarioB","scenarioB")
scenarioB <- cbind(rownames(scenarioB),scenarioB, scenario)
rownames(scenarioB) <- NULL
colnames(scenarioB) <- c("endpoint","hits","scenario")
#I create a new data frame with scenarios A & B
scenarios <- as.data.frame(rbind(scenarioA, scenarioB))
scenarios$endpoint <- as.character(c("count_0", "count_1","count_2","count_3","count_4","count_5","count_6","count_7",
           "count_8","count_9","count_10","count_11","count_12","count_13","count_14","count_15"))
scenarios$endpoint <- factor(scenarios$endpoint, levels=unique(scenarios$endpoint))
scenarios$hits <- as.numeric(as.character(scenarios$hits))
#I plot the results in one single graph to compare the 2 scenarios
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(scenarios, aes(x=endpoint, y=hits, color=scenario))+
  geom_point()+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(hjust=.5))
```

The code runs but it is not straightforward. Ultimately I will work with more than 2 scenarios and so I would like to find a better way to write this. I thought of looping and/or nesting.

Comment: Well, you *definitely* have a bug, because when I enter your code I get `Error in group_vars(x) : object 'data' not found`. Could it be that you forgot to give us some [minimal example data](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to work with? :-)

Comment: I added a link to a Google Sheet with my data. Hope it's ok.

Comment: Please add your data as  a `dput` and include current and expected output. Use `dput(head(df,n))`. Choose `n` as necessary. Also, so many calls to sum make it look overly complicating things, perhaps there's a simpler way. Hard to tell without your data. **Share data as a dput object not links**

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the scenarios differ in the order of the columns.

```
colA <- colnames(data)[2:16]
colB <- colnames(data)[c(14, 4, 6, 9, 7, 2, 5, 16, 10, 8, 3, 11, 13, 15, 12)]
```

We do one more thing to simplify our work, namely replace all 0's by NA. If the distinction between 0 and NA is important to you, it is not obvious from your question. We will use dplyr in the following.

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data %>% mutate_all(~ ifelse(. == 0, NA, .))
```

Now, to get the counts. There is a multitude of options, I have chosen one that is relatively easy to follow:

```
count_runs <- function(data, cols) {
  data %>% select(cols) %>% drop_na %>% count %>% pull(n)
}
```

Alternatives:

```
# without removing NA's
count_runs <- function(data, cols) {
  data %>% select(cols) %>% drop_na %>% 
     filter_all(all_vars(. == 1)) %>%    # important notice below!
     count %>% pull(n)
}

# without dplyr
# and without converting 0's to NA's
count_runs <- function(data, cols) {
    data <- data[, cols]
    sum(apply(data, 1, function(x) all(!is.na(x) & x == 1)))
}
```

All these functions return exactly the same results.

This function removes all NA containing rows (that is, rows where the values are not all equal to 1) and counts how many rows remain. The result of running `count_runs(data, colA[1:3])` is, for example, 84.

Now we can make scenarioA and scenarioB:

```
 endpoints <- 0:15
 counts <- sapply(1:15, function(i) count_runs(data, colA[1:i]))
 counts <- c(nrow(data), counts)
 scenarioA <- data.frame(endpoint=endpoints, hits=counts, scenario="scenarioA")
 counts <- sapply(1:15, function(i) count_runs(data, colB[1:i]))
 counts <- c(nrow(data), counts)
 scenarioB <- data.frame(endpoint=endpoints, hits=counts, scenario="scenarioB")
 scenarios <- rbind(scenarioA, scenarioB)
```

Finally, the plot:

```
 ggplot(scenarios, aes(x=endpoint, y=hits, color=scenario, group=scenario)) + 
       geom_point() + geom_line() + theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Now, a couple of remarks.

- The code you provided doesn't work. First, in one line you have "M", "C" etc. instead of "colM", "colC" etc. Then, the counts are NA due to the fact that you do `sum(...)` instead of `sum(..., na.rm=T)` and some of the columns are filled with NA's.
- `as.numeric(as.character(hits))` – I assume at one point or another you have been hurt by a factor that looked like a number. That is not the way to solve it; `sum()` will return a number always, and you can always check that the data type is correct.
- Why are you converting `endpoint` to a character value? It does not look well on the plot with all these labels, and it actually corresponds to a series of consecutive numbers.
- **Important:** Your data is of type *double* (floating point). That means that you should *never, ever* use `==` or `%in%` to do anything with that data. Either use `all_equal` or, better, change the data type to integer.
- Next time you post such a question, please help those who want to help you: select a subset of your data and use `dput` to directly embed it in your post. Actually, you should do it even though I already answered your question, for the sake of others who might be interested in your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. I inserted a subset of my data using dput. I corrected the mistake ("M" instead of "colM").
I am not sure I understand the lines `colA <- colnames(data)[2:16]` and 
`colB <- colnames(data)[c(14, 4, 6, 9, 7, 2, 5, 16, 10, 8, 3, 11, 13, 15, 12)]`. Is it ordering the columns in a specific order (indicated in c(x1,x2...))?

Comment: Yes. Try for example `c("A", "B", "C")[c(3, 1, 2)]`. Here, the resulting vectors are in the same order in which you are doing the logical operations in your code.

Comment: For one of my scenario, I would like to take into account the "0" as well, and not only the "1" contrary to what was done before. So instead of looking at the observations that meet all conditions successively, I would like the observations that meet a condition after not meeting the previous conditions.
So basically, I have a step wise approach. At each step I can either have a 1 or a 0. I would like to count the observations for which I have a 0 after a 1 and this for all conditions consecutively. Does it make sense?